# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

So this is my code:

```
class Rostercheck(commands.Cog, name='Rostercheck'):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.roster = {
            "sast" : {"roster": "PLACEHOLDER", "discordid_range":'PLACEHOLDER'}
        }   
        self.guild_metadata = {"sast": PLACEHOLDER}
        self.channel_metadata = {
            "sast": {"roster_check": PLACEHOLDER}
        }
        self.check_discord_members.start()

    async def send_message(self, content, channel=None):
        try:
            await channel.send(content)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Encountered exception: {e}")

    async def get_roster_sheet(self, dept_name):
        scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
        service_account_file = './keys.json'
        creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_file, scopes=scopes)
        service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
        my_dept_roster = self.roster.get(dept_name)
        sheet = service.spreadsheets()
        return sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=my_dept_roster.get("roster"),range=my_dept_roster.get("discordid_range")).execute()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=100)
    async def check_discord_members(self):
        print("yo")
        for dept_name in self.roster.keys():
            print(dept_name)
            google_sheet = await self.get_roster_sheet(dept_name)
            print(google_sheet)
            for value_list in google_sheet.get("values"):
                print(value_list)
                if len(value_list) != 1 or value_list is None or "Discord ID" in value_list:
                    continue
                value = value_list[0]
                print(value)
                discord_server = self.bot.get_guild(self.guild_metadata.get(dept_name))
                print(discord_server)
                discord_member = discord_server.get_member(int(re.sub("[^0-9]", "", value)))
                print(discord_member)
                if discord_member is None:
                    my_chan = self.bot.get_channel(id=self.channel_metadata.get(dept_name).get("roster_check"))
                    print(my_chan)
                    await self.send_message(f"{value} - <@{value}> is not within the {dept_name} roster, are you sure they are still in your department?", my_chan)  

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Rostercheck(bot))
```

I had it print each step of the process, but it breaks right at the print(discord_server) and it gives the error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_member'`

The code is supposed to read discordid from a google sheet, and check if those discordids are still in that specific discord server.

The get_guild, get_member, and get_channel are just being really weird and I am not sure if it is because the code is in a cog causing it to just break as or if there is another issue but I have ensured everything outside of the code is working.

Comment: Could be a cache problem if you ask me. `NoneType` always means that something does not exist.

Comment: Are you sure that your bot is still in the guild you are trying to get?
And what value do you get from `self.guild_metadata.get(dept_name)`? Is it a valid guild id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's most likely a cache issue as Dominik said and since [`get_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) gets the guild from the cache and doesn't make an API call it returns `None`. So instead using [`fetch_guild()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=get_guild#discord.Client.get_guild) should solve this issue.

```py
discord_server = self.bot.fetch_guild(self.guild_metadata.get(dept_name))
```

---

If this doesn't work another issue might be the guild ID being a string in which case you will need to parse it into an integer first.

```py
discord_server = self.bot.fetch_guild(int(self.guild_metadata.get(dept_name)))
```

Comment: Thanks this worked as fix for this error code, but I am now getting a weird error I can't even find on stackoverflow so get ready for that question haha!

Comment: Your note about ID being a string saved me. Thanks!